# Create new column based on old column using a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dictionary, mapping

I've seen some posts that work when the dictionary uses one value per key. However, I would like to use a dictionary with multiple values per key.

```
myDict = {'0': ['a', 'b', 'c'], '1': ['e', 'f'], '2': ['z','x','y']}
```

I would to create a new column so all `a`, `b` and `c` become `0` and so forth, resulting in:

```
col1, col2
a, 0
f, 1
a, 0
x, 2
e, 1
```

Based on a couple other answers I tried this, but it did not work:
`df['col2'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: a for a, b in myDict.items() if x in b)`

My other thought is to just create a dictionary like `{'a':'0', 'b':'0'}` and map that, but I was curious as to a more succinct way if my lists were very long (each key had a list of 30 values). Or is that the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Let us using `Series` with `stack`

```
pd.Series(myDict).apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=0)
Out[353]: 
  level_0  0
0       0  a
1       0  b
2       0  c
0       1  e
1       1  f
0       2  z
1       2  x
2       2  y
```

Updated

```
s=pd.Series(myDict).apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=0).set_index(0)['level_0']
s.get(df.col1)
Out[372]: 
col1
a    0
f    1
a    0
x    2
e    1
Name: level_0, dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks! so I would then convert this to a dictionary similar to what @tobsecret suggested, and then map that dictionary onto my original column? Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: @As3adTintin yes you can try with it

Comment: thanks! it seems like nans are throwing this off and adding `np.nan : np.nan` to the dictionary doesn't help. any suggestion on that?

Comment: I've ended up going with this so far (if anyone reads this in the future. It works, not sure if it's ideal. Thanks again for the help, Wen. `myDict= pd.Series(eduDict).apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=0).set_index(0)['level_0'].to_dict()`  `df['col2'] = df['col1'].map(myDict)`

Answer (score 0):

Given that your col1 only contains these values 'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', etc.), you can use the following:

```
myDict = {'a':0, 'b':'0', 'c':'0', 'e':'1', 'f':'1', 'z':'2', 'x':'2', 'y':'2'}
df.col1.map(myDict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension and feed into `pd.DataFrame`. This is usually more efficient than manipulating an existing dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'0': ['a', 'b', 'c'], '1': ['e', 'f'], '2': ['z','x','y']}

df = pd.DataFrame([[w, k] for k, v in d.items() for w in v],
                  columns=['col1', 'col2'])

print(df)

  col1 col2
0    a    0
1    b    0
2    c    0
3    e    1
4    f    1
5    z    2
6    x    2
7    y    2
```

Comment: thanks but I want to create a new column based on an already existing column, not just create a new df with the unique combinations